# Is there a way to create columns out of rows depending on row's adjacent value?

Tags: excel, vba

Initially, I started off with CSV data which I cleaned/filtered out. It's a very large data set. Here's what I am hoping to accomplish:

[image]

What I have tried:

My approach was to first copy the column with names to a new sheet, next remove all duplicates, and then use match and index to create new columns. Unfortunately, due to large data size excel crashes.

Are there any excel commands I can use? Or perhaps VBA? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try Pivot Tables ?

Comment: Pivot won't do the Job for you, as you don't just have integers in Value. You should go with `VBA` and Use `Arrays` for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that source data is in columns `A:C` and output is in `E:H` columns:

```
Sub TransposeTable()
    Dim lastRow&, r&, x&, j&
    x = 1: r = 2
    While Len(Cells(r, "A")) > 0
        x = x + 1
        lastRow = Columns("A:A").Find(Cells(r, "A"), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Cells(x, "E") = Cells(r, "A")
        For j = r To lastRow
            Cells(x, GetColumn(Cells(j, "C"))) = Cells(j, "B")
        Next
        r = lastRow + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Private Function GetColumn&(strAttribute)
    Select Case strAttribute
        Case "Weight": GetColumn = 6
        Case "Age":    GetColumn = 7
        Case "Height": GetColumn = 8
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column as shown in the image below in cell **D2** ...

[image]

... then as you can see on the right hand side, I have the transformed table.

In cell **G2**, this is the formula ...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($F2 & "_" & G$1,$D:$D,0)),"")
```

... now fill that down and across the rest of the grid.

If that doesn't work for you then you can always use a macro.  Depends on the size of your data and how painful it is to maintain that matrix manually.

Comment: Ha ha, just read the rest of your question.  I think I supplied the answer you weren't looking for.  So let me confirm, that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This code will get data from the source worksheet named "Sheet1". The last row is automatically detected. It assumes that data starts in row 2 (1st row is reserved for headers that aren't used). The macro creates output in a sheet named "Sheet2".

First, 2 collections are created for unique names and types. Thanks to this we know how big the output table will be and have all possible values, to which we can find matches in the second iteration.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ProcessData()

    Dim vSource As Variant, vOut() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, nCounter As Long, outNameCounter As Long, outTypeCounter As Long
    Dim colNames As New Collection, colTypes As New Collection
    Dim itm

    Const nameCol As Long = 1
    Const valueCol As Long = 2
    Const typeCol As Long = 3

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'source worksheet named "Sheet1"
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        vSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 3))
    End With

    For nCounter = LBound(vSource) + 1 To UBound(vSource) 'skip header
        On Error Resume Next
        colNames.Add vSource(nCounter, nameCol), CStr(vSource(nCounter, nameCol))
        colTypes.Add vSource(nCounter, typeCol), CStr(vSource(nCounter, typeCol))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next nCounter

    ReDim vOut(1 + colNames.Count, 1 + colTypes.Count) 'create output table based on unique names and types count

    vOut(1, 1) = "Name"

    For nCounter = 1 To colNames.Count 'fill output table names
        vOut(nCounter + 1, 1) = colNames(nCounter)
    Next nCounter

    For nCounter = 1 To colTypes.Count 'fill output table types
        vOut(1, nCounter + 1) = colTypes(nCounter)
    Next nCounter

    For nCounter = LBound(vSource) + 1 To UBound(vSource) 'match source table data with output table names and types
        For outNameCounter = LBound(vOut) + 1 To UBound(vOut)
            If vSource(nCounter, nameCol) = vOut(outNameCounter, nameCol) Then
                For outTypeCounter = LBound(vOut, 2) + 1 To UBound(vOut, 2)
                    If vSource(nCounter, typeCol) = vOut(1, outTypeCounter) Then
                        vOut(outNameCounter, outTypeCounter) = vSource(nCounter, valueCol)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next outTypeCounter
                Exit For
            End If
        Next outNameCounter
    Next nCounter

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'output worksheet named "Sheet2"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Cells.ClearContents 'clear contents of whole worksheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(vOut), UBound(vOut, 2))) = vOut 'paste output table
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the idea of using remove duplicates but you should use arrays for the one-to-one tranfers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeValues()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, types As Variant, names As Variant
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet5")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(after:=ws1)

    'set up types
    With ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, "C"), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        ws2.Cells(1, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With
    With ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, "A"), ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    With ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, "A"), ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .Cells(1, "A").Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count) = _
          Application.Transpose(.Value)
        .Clear
    End With

    'set up names
    With ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, "A"), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        ws2.Cells(1, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With
    With ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, "A"), ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With

    'collect source array
    arr1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, "A"), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).Value

    'create target array and matrix header arrays
    With ws2
        arr2 = .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion.Cells.Value
        types = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
        names = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    'move source to target
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr1, 1)
        arr2(Application.Match(arr1(i, 1), names, 0), _
             Application.Match(arr1(i, 3), types, 0)) = arr1(i, 2)
    Next i

    'transfer target array to worksheet
    ws2.Cells(1, "A").Resize(UBound(arr2, 1), UBound(arr2, 2)) = arr2

    'name new target worksheet
    ws2.Name = "Target"

End Sub
```